# Django URLs regex

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I need you help to validate a regular expression link in Python. Here's how should the link look like:

```
http://www.example.com?utm_source=something&utm_medium=somethingelse
```

And I've tried something like:

```
r'^\?utm_source\=(?P<utm_source>[-\w]+)&utm_medium\=(?P<utm_medium>[-\w]+)/$'
```

But this doesn't work. Can you please help me? Which (other) characters should be escaped?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are those spaces really there `(?P < utm_source)`?

Comment: no, there are not. if I would have deleted the spaces, the code would not have been printed ok. so ignore those spaces.

Comment: Why do you think you need regular expressions? What are you *actually* trying to validate?

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the editing controls before posting incorrect code. I'll format your post for you so you can see how it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/147331).

[Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554223/django-urls-regex-help/7554300#7554300), gives you the solution you asked for.

I'd suggest that you do not need regular expressions here at all if all you want to do is validate a query string.

Take a look at [`urlparse`](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/urlparse.html)...

```
>>> a_url = 'http://www.example.com?utm_source=something&utm_medium=somethingelse'
>>> parser = urlparse.urlparse(a_url)
>>> qs = urlparse.parse_qs(parser.query)
>>> 'utm_medium' in qs
True
>>> len(qs['utm_medium']) == 1
True
>>> qs['utm_medium'][0].isalpha()
True
>>> 'utm_source' in qs
True
>>> len(qs['utm_source']) == 1
True
>>> qs['utm_source'][0].isalpha()
True
>>> 'utm_zone' in qs
False
```

Comment: I suppose this is probably the backend behind some of the request object. Using request.GET may be more straight-forward depending on what the OP want to do. `if 'utm_medium' in request.GET: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those escapes:

```
r'^\?utm_source=(?P<utm_source>[-\w]+)&utm_medium=(?P<utm_medium>[-\w]+)/$'
```

Then, your regex only matches a complete string; it won't find a sub-match, so perhaps you need to remove the anchors?

```
r'\?utm_source=(?P<utm_source>[-\w]+)&utm_medium=(?P<utm_medium>[-\w]+)/'
```

Finally, the slash at the end is required in the regex but missing from your example string. So how about

```
r'\?utm_source=(?P<utm_source>[-\w]+)&utm_medium=(?P<utm_medium>[-\w]+)/?'
```